# visual studio debug not work after first run plus bunch of errors

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

when I open visual studio and run my solution it works fine the first time, debugging break point hit correctly. BUT second time I get a lot of errors that mysteriously disappear when I click them, and debug point are NO LONGER hit. It works if I rebuild the whole solution, but I cant do that on every run, it takes a long time.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Reproduce it and paste them here. Also we can help if you paste minimal code.

Comment: Its a huge project, I get 387 errors, which are not errors anymore when I click them.

Comment: Do you understand? I double click the errors in the error list tab and then they slowly disappear. I cannot be the only one who experienced this. I tried on two different pc's and 2 different OS, thats not the problem.

Comment: Its a website with extra 3 layers(3 more projects in the solution), model, business and data layer, compiling into dll's in the website bin folder. None of the errors I get are actually errors. They all appear in the website project and strangely ebough, that have nothing to do with the other layers, they are all UI errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I could wait more than 10 hours for an answer and the answer was a dual one. 
1: I had a wrong dll reference path, I found out by deleting the bin and obj folders and noticing that all the UI error were connected to one particular dll.
2: Disabled the "Just My Code" option in the Debug/General settings.

Now everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I open my computer this morning super ready for another business week, but VS 2015 decided That just because everything was ok yesterday, does not mean they are today. Same errors again and now I cant debug at all. Wonderful.