# Visual studio 2015 build error

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have come across a wierd vis studio error which only had one other question I could find that is [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389762/visual-studio-debug-not-work-after-first-run-plus-bunch-of-errors).

When I try to debug the code I hit run and it says there are errors would I like to run the last working version to which I say no. This then comes up with 91 errors which slowly disappear until there are none left.

This may be quite hard to understand what is actually going on, so I have recorded it to make things a bit easier.

[Link to video](https://youtu.be/5etdtr9lrzM)

I have no idea what is going on and cant seem to find anything other than that other question, which the guy did solve but the next day he turned on his computer the same thing happened, I don't want to be fixing this everyday.

Any Suggestions would be great!

Thanks

Comment: have you installed the Update2? if not, try it

Comment: Yeah it was on update 2, I have no idea what was wrong with it but I have it working for now anyway. Who knows when something like that will happen again.

Answer (score 0):

All fixed now, I still have no idea what was wrong with it. I just deleted it all and pulled it back down from TFS and it worked, it is a bit of a strange one.

Comment: Posting a video of compilation errors is a crazy thing to do, Sam. In the future, you should (1) copy and paste the compiler errors (or the build output if you can't copy and paste from the Error List), (2) include a sample of code that reproduces the problem. For errors in particular, the error number is critically important. I think I can read BC30002 in the video, but I'm not certain. I would have been certain if you'd posted the actual text. It would also be searchable for future Googlers. Anyway, you probably would have fixed it by cleaning and rebuilding. Always a good thing to try.

Comment: Yeah I only recorded it because it was hard to explain what was going on and I've never seen that happen before, It's near impossible for me to show the errors disappearing otherwise and I assumed as the errors were going away that was nothing to do with the problem.

Cleaning and rebuilding did not work I had to straight up remove the projects get them from the repository and import them individually into the solution. 

Thanks for the heads up anyway, I wouldn't normally post a video but I couldn't think of any other way to show what was happening.